# ESP NOW failing using WIFI_AP_STA and WiFi.begin but working without the WiFi.begin

Tags: wifi, esp32

I am using code derived from Rui Santos https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp-now-esp32-arduino-ide/

I am using ESP NOW to send readings from an ESP32 sender to an ESP32 receiver then using the ESP32 receiver to send an html message to a ESP32 web server.  Per Rui's instructions I need to start WiFi with WIFI_AP_STA to allow both wifi connection methods.

The sender and receiver code is below.

If I run the code as is, i.e. the receiver setup as WIFI_AP_STA but with the WiFi.begin line commented out, I get a sender status of:
[Send success](https://i.stack.imgur.com/k5F9P.jpg), and a receive status of:[Receive status](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ooCUS.jpg).  SO there is no problem sending an ESP NOW message from the sender to the receiver (also works with WIFI_STA).

If I use WIFI_AP_STA and uncomment the line in the receiver "WiFi.begin(SSIS, PASSWORD)" so that I can send a message to the ESP32 web server, I get a send status of:[Send fail](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dmkQe.jpg), and a receive status of:[Receive status with failed send](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hETOQ.jpg).  The send fails but the receive is still successful. Same fail if I use WIFI_AP. It seems that in WIFI_AP_STA mode with a WiFi.begin, the receiver sends an incorrect status back to the sender.

In summary, on the receiver, using wifi mode WIFI_AP_STA without a WiFi.begin, works for sending an ESP NOW message from sender to receiver, as it should.

Using wifi mode WIFI_AP_STA and WiFi.begin on the receiver, the sender fails when sending an ESP NOW message.  When I implement the web code the web html message send works. However the issue can be reproduced using the simplified code below.

Using WiFi@2.0.0.

I've run out of ideas, is anyone able to point me at further investigation areas?

My sender code is:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>
// Rui Santos https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp-now-esp32-arduino-ide/
uint8_t broadcastAddress[] = {0x24, 0x6F, 0x28, 0xAA, 0x84, 0x10};
typedef struct struct_message
{
  char ESP32NowText[33];
} struct_message;
struct_message ESP32NowMessage;
//
String text = "AAA000010000200003000040000500006";
esp_now_peer_info_t peerInfo;
// callback when data is sent
void OnDataSent(const uint8_t *mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status)
{
  Serial.print("\r\nLast Packet Send Status:\t");
  Serial.println(status == ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS ? "Delivery Success" : "Delivery Fail");
}
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_STA);
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  esp_now_register_send_cb(OnDataSent);
  // Register peer
  memcpy(peerInfo.peer_addr, broadcastAddress, 6);
  peerInfo.channel = 0;
  peerInfo.encrypt = false;
  // Add peer
  if (esp_now_add_peer(&peerInfo) != ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("Failed to add peer");
    return;
  }
}
void loop()
{
  strncpy(ESP32NowMessage.ESP32NowText, text.c_str(), text.length());
  Serial.println("Msg to send:" + String(ESP32NowMessage.ESP32NowText));
  Serial.println("Snd Len:" + String(sizeof(ESP32NowMessage)));
  // Send message via ESP-NOW
  esp_err_t result = esp_now_send(broadcastAddress, (uint8_t *)&ESP32NowMessage, sizeof(ESP32NowMessage));
  if (result == ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("Sent with success");
  }
  else
  {
    Serial.println("Error sending the data");
  }
  delay(2000);
}
```

My receiver code is:

```
#include <Arduino.h>
#include <WiFi.h>
#include <esp_now.h>
 // Rui Santos https://RandomNerdTutorials.com/esp-now-esp32-arduino-ide/
typedef struct struct_message
{
  char ESP32NowValues[33];
} struct_message;
struct_message ESP32NowMessage;
// callback function that will be executed when data is received
void OnDataRecv(const uint8_t *mac, const uint8_t *incomingData, int len)
{
  memcpy(&ESP32NowMessage, incomingData, sizeof(ESP32NowMessage));
  Serial.println("Bytes received: " + String(len));
  Serial.println("Values:" + String(ESP32NowMessage.ESP32NowValues));
  Serial.println("---------------------------------------");
}
const char WiFiSSID[] = "SSID";
const char WiFiPassword[] = "PASSWORD";
//
void setup()
{
  Serial.begin(115200);
  WiFi.mode(WIFI_AP_STA);
  // WiFi.begin(WiFiSSID, WiFiPassword);
  // Init ESP-NOW
  if (esp_now_init() != ESP_OK)
  {
    Serial.println("Error initializing ESP-NOW");
    return;
  }
  esp_now_register_recv_cb(OnDataRecv);
}
void loop()
{
}
```

Comment: WiFi an esp-now can't be used together

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to send data to the receiver using the same channel it is using on the WiFi gateway. The channel is set on the receiver after running `WiFi.begin(WiFiSSID, WiFiPassword);`, according to the WiFi gateway configuration.

### Method 1

You can find the channel by adding this line `WiFi.printDiag(Serial);` after `WiFi.begin(WiFiSSID, WiFiPassword);` in your receiver code. Then set the channel manually in the sender code with:

```cpp
esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
esp_wifi_set_channel(channel, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
```

Where `channel` is the integer you need to replace.

### Method 2

You can save the `WiFiSSID` in the sender code and use it to find the channel without having to write it down in case it changes over time:

```cpp
cost char *WiFiSSID = "YOUR SSID";

int32_t getWiFiChannel(const char *ssid) {
    if (int32_t n = WiFi.scanNetworks()) {
        for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
            if (!strcmp(ssid, WiFi.SSID(i).c_str())) {
                return WiFi.channel(i);
            }
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

In your `setup()` function, include the following lines:

```cpp
int32_t channel = getWiFiChannel(WiFiSSID);
esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
esp_wifi_set_channel(channel, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
```

### Method 3 (recommended)

You can use the callback function to offset the channel until ESP-NOW communications are confirmed:

```cpp
uint8_t channel = 1;

void tryNextChannel() {
  Serial.println("Changing channel from " + String(channel) + " to " + String(channel+1));
  channel = channel % 13 + 1;
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(true);
  esp_wifi_set_channel(channel, WIFI_SECOND_CHAN_NONE);
  esp_wifi_set_promiscuous(false);
}


void onDataSent(const uint8_t* mac_addr, esp_now_send_status_t status) {
  if (!channelFound && status != ESP_NOW_SEND_SUCCESS) {
    Serial.println("Delivery Fail because channel" + String(channel) + " does not match receiver channel.");
    tryNextChannel(); // If message was not delivered, it tries on another wifi channel.
  }
  else {
    Serial.println("Delivery Successful ! Using channel : " + String(channel));
    channelFound = true;
  }
}
```

When initializing ESP-NOW, just add this line: `esp_now_register_send_cb(onDataSent);`.

If you would like to see a basic example of ESP-NOW communication that works with a WiFi gateway, you can take a look at my Github repository: https://github.com/lukalafaye/ESP-NOW-WiFi-Gateway.

Answer (score 1):

Modifying the previous answer slightly, I have successfully used both Wi-Fi, and ESPNOW, between two ESP8266's. My transmitter ESP8266 is connected to a temperature sensor and only transmits using ESP-NOW. (No WiFi).

My ESP8266 receiver first uses WiFi to set it's clock, then it disconnects from WiFi and uses ESP-NOW to receive temperature data from my remote transmitter.

From the Espressif documentation:
"Can Wi-Fi be used with ESP-NOW at the same time?
Yes, but it should be noted that the channel of ESP-NOW must be the same as that of the connected AP."

Simply add to the end of void setup() on the receiver:

```
int chan;
if (int32_t n = WiFi.scanNetworks()) {
    for (uint8_t i=0; i<n; i++) {
        if (!strcmp(ssid, WiFi.SSID(i).c_str())) {
            chan = WiFi.channel(i); } } }

wifi_set_channel(chan);
```

My transmitter doesn't need WiFi (only ESP-NOW), so nothing had to be added.

Before I added this communication was VERY unreliable. I manually changed channels on my WiFi modem to confirm this would work.